# Is there a way to enable emoji on TouchBar for every text field?

Tags: emoji, touch-bar

I don't see any other advantages of TouchBar xD. So emoji enabled only in certain apple apps.

I know, that it's app support story, but what about browsers? I want, for example, to use emoji in Facebook chat, or other web based chats in Chrome.

Comment: Why are you editing the question in that way?! It loses the original meaning. I don't use Facebook Chat, I just mentioned it for an example. I really need this functionality in **every text field.**

Comment: I agree, the edit changed your question drastically. You're always welcome to edit your questions yourself if you feel this occurred, which I agree is what happened here. I've edited the question in an attempt to be more aligned with what you had previously — cc @Graham

Comment: Sorry. The original question was broad and my aim was to avoid your question being closed as such.

Comment: Maybe better touch Tool can accomplish that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the Touch Bar support emoji for every field?

Yes.  The touch bar will support practically anything the developer wants to include.  The more appropriate question is, *can you enable it?*

Not unless the developer of the app allows you to.

The Touch Bar is an extension of the UI and is meant as another interface that the developer can utilize the enhance the experience.  See [About The Touch Bar](http://radnex.us/about-the-touchbar).

So, from the same document, you can see that emogis are available via the character picker but that character picker won't be available in the App unless the App developer enables it.

[image]

Comment: That's true, I know it. But I found a script for enabling TouchID for `sudo`. Just thought there can be another one, evoking character picker, when cursor is in the text field.

Comment: Can you share the script?

Comment: Sure. https://github.com/hamzasood/pam_touchid

Comment: Ahhh.. I see what it's doing...The "app" is actually a PAM module (authentication) that's engaging the Touch Bar.  Once that module is finished, the Touch Bar is at the "mercy" of the app that's currently active.  So, technically, you could run a script that enables the char picker, but once you switch to the application you want to use the picker in, it would take control of the picker and put the controls it wants in the bar "overriding" your script.

Comment: Ok, in that case it does not need to be a script. There is an app called "AppSwitcher". It add an icon to TouchBar, that evokes the dock in TouchBar. So may be there is an app, that adds a permanent icon of the character picker to the bar. But I think this app will have to duplicate the charpicker functionality instead of evoking core charpicker. So I'll wait for our dear Google to implement that feature =)